# Matlab (How to fit multiple data sets )

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

Suppose I have for vectors x1, y1, x2, y2, and I would like to plot this data (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) with different colors. The dimesions of vector x1,y1 are not the same with x2,y2.
Than I would like also to fit all this data together, with the same polynomial fit, degree 1.

Can someone help me to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can plot the vectors simply using `plot`:

```
plot(x1, y1, 'r.', x2, y2, 'b.')
```

where the `'r.'` specifies that this first pair should be plotted in red dots, and the `'b.'` specifies that the second pair should be plotted in blue dots. You can find a more complete list of color/marker options in the help documentation for `plot`.

To fit a polynomial to (x,y) data, you can use `polyfit`:

```
poly_coeffs = polyfit( x, y, poly_degree )
```

If you want to fit the same polynomial to both sets of data, you should concatenate your vectors into a single vector, e.g. (in the case of row vectors):

```
x = [x1, x2]
y = [y1, y2]
poly_coeffs = polyfit( x, y, poly_degree )
```

If you have column vectors, you would use `x = [x1; x2]` (note the semicolon instead of the comma) to concatenate them vertically.

And now if you wanted to plot the polynomial fit on top of the original data, you can add it on to the list of arguments to `plot`:

```
curve_x = linspace( min(x), max(x), 100 );
curve_y = polyval( poly_coeffs, curve_x );
plot(x1,y1,'r.', x2,y2,'b.', curve_x,curve_y,'k-');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was what I wanted. I tried also for 3 set of vectors and it is working well. Thank you!