# Plotting a Line of Best Fit on the Same Plot for Multiple Datasets

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to approximate a line of best fit between multiple datasets, and display everything on one plot. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27048842/matlab-how-to-fit-multiple-data-sets/) addresses a similar notion, but the contents are in MatLab and, hence, not the same.

I have data from 4 different experiments that's composed of `146` values, the `Y` values represent changes in distance over time, the `X` value, which is represented by integer timesteps `(1,2,3,...)`. The shape of my Y data is `(4,146)`, as I've decided to keep all of it in a nested list, and the shape of my X data is `(146,)`. I have the following set-up for my subplots:

```
x = [i for i in range(len(temp[0]))]
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.scatter(x,Y[0],c="blue", marker='.',linewidth=1)
ax1.scatter(x,Y[1],c="orange", marker='.',linewidth=1)
ax1.scatter(x,Y[2],c="green", marker='.',linewidth=1)
ax1.scatter(x,Y[3],c="purple", marker='.',linewidth=1)

z = np.polyfit(x,Y,3) # Throws an error because x,Y are not the same length
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(x, p(x))
```

I do not know how to fit a line of best fit between the scatter plots. `numpy.polyfit` documentation suggests that "[Several data sets of sample points sharing the same x-coordinates can be fitted at once](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)", but I have been unsuccessful thus far, and can only fit the line to one dataset. Is there a way that I can fit the line to all of the data sets? Should I use a different library entirely, like Seaborn?

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast `x` and `Y` to a numpy arrays (I assume it is in a list). You can do this by using `x = np.asarray(x)`. Now to fit on the data collectively, you can flatten the `Y` array using `Y.flatten()`. It transforms the shape from `(n,N)` to `(n*N)`. And you can tile the `x` array `n` times to make a fit, this just copies the array `n` times into a new array so this will also become shape `(n*N,)`. In this way you match the values form `Y` to corresponding values of `x`.

```
N = 10 # no. datapoints
n = 4  # no. experiments

# creating some dummy data
x = np.linspace(0,1, N)  # shape (N,)
Y = np.random.normal(0,1,(n, N))

np.polyfit(np.tile(x, n), Y.flatten(), deg=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `polyfit` function expects the `Y` array to be, in your case, `(146, 4)` rather than `(4, 146)`, so you should pass it the transpose of `Y`, e.g.,

```py
z = np.polyfit(x, Y.T, 3)
```

The `poly1d` function can only do one polynomial at a time, so you have to loop over the results from `polyfit`, e.g.,:

```py
for res in z:
    p = np.poly1d(res)
    plt.plot(x, p(x))
```